# Sortable columns on a fixed-layout table in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, html-table

I'm attempting to create a table with reorderable columns using jQuery UI's "sortable" interaction.  However, I'm having trouble on IE with `table-layout: fixed`.

The sortable is attached to the table's `thead > tr` and works just fine.  The table looks correct when not dragging a column heading.  While dragging, however, IE increases the width of the table to 100% and makes the dragged heading's column wider to make up the difference.  I've tried specifying the width via `<col>` elements (which seem to be completely ignored by IE?), setting widths on each `<td>`, using `forcePlaceholderSize`, and combinations of the three, but nothing seems to work.

Code is below and on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MApsB/2/).  Note that the logic to actually swap columns and correct their widths after dragging is finished hasn't been included; right now, I'm only concerned with the (mis-)behavior *while* dragging.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <col style="width:90px">
    <col style="width:130px">
    <col style="width:70px">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:90px">width 90</th>
            <th style="width:130px">width 130</th>
            <th style="width:70px">width 70</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:90px">foo</td>
            <td style="width:130px">bar</td>
            <td style="width:70px">baz</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width:90px">wibble</td>
            <td style="width:130px">wobble</td>
            <td style="width:70px">wubble</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width:90px">lorem</td>
            <td style="width:130px">ipsum</td>
            <td style="width:70px">dolor</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td, th {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 0 .25em;
}
```

JS:

```
$("thead tr").sortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    helper: "clone",
    tolerance: "pointer"
});
```